# Infinite Plane of charge between two grounded conducting planes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, voltage, conductors

**A question from Zhangwill:**

[image: Zhangwill Q 5.4]

I understand how to arrive at the "correct" solution. Pictured below.  It is illogical (even if it follows from solution) that sigma of conducting planes could have dependance on the position of plane. E due to a plane is invariant under translation. 
My purposed solution: send interior sigmas on the conducting planes to (+/-) infinity, and exterior sigmas on the external to opposite sign respective to the interior sigma on the plane. Then phi constant/zero and E zero for all z. What is wrong with this solution?

Zhangwill Solution:

[image]

Comment: What is $\sigma'$? And please clarify what you mean by "send sigma on the conducting planes to infinity" and why this should lead to zero potential.

Comment: Sorry, this is not an answer.
For the inner surface with electric charges distributed, how does Zhangwill prove that the surface and back surface potentials are equal (i.e. $\phi(z)$ in his expression)?

Comment: @Puk surface charge of the conductors (on the “inner side” of each). I am purposing 1 to positive infinity one to negative infinity.  The E field would be uniformly zero in such a situation and phi would then be a constant which could be set to zero

Comment: Are you suggesting that the infinite central plate is “connected” to infinity and hence is at a zero potential?

Comment: @Farcher, I am saying that if the surface charge with extremely large the potential and E due to central plane would be negligible. I made a few edits should I clarify post further or is it better now?

Comment: @Hemmi he doesn’t as far as I know. This is the grounded case not the ungrounded one. He’s says inner side conductor has charge s.t. E is zero on the other side. Thus, outer side has no charge. Is this what you were asking?

Comment: @Eric, I commented because I thought that the potential would be different on both sides of the charge distribution if the charge distribution were not flat but had a thickness.
But the problem was the thickness was zero, so my comment was inappropriate. my apologies.

Comment: @HEMMI as far as I know they do have thickness because idk how we could describe their behavior without using $E_inside=0$. My prof told me outside sigma's were zero, but I have no idea why that would be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the solution you show contains a mistake. The charge density on the left plate should be $\sigma' = \frac{z-d}{2d}\sigma$, with $-\sigma -\sigma'=\frac{-z-d}{2d}\sigma$ on the right plate. The solution you show finds $\sigma'$ with the same sign as $\sigma$, which doesn't make sense.

I'm still not sure I understand your proposed solution. You are saying one plate should have a charge density approaching positive infinity, and the other approaching negative infinity, and that this would create a zero E-field. This is not correct, there would be a very large E-field pointing from the positive plate to the negative, and so the positive plate would be at a higher potential. This clearly doesn't satisfy the condition that the plates be grounded.

Comment: Shoot! I totally cut off the picture that went with the solution! That’s my bad! I will update. You are probably right abt solution manual being wrong. I remember getting something slightly different than solution manual and chalking it up using dif set-up than Zhangwill.

Comment: Can you explain why this wouldn’t satisfy grounding? If E = 0 for z, isn’t potential a free constant which I can set to zero

Comment: @Eric Like I said, the E-field wouldn't be zero, it would be very large.

Comment: Oh my goodness, you are right. Ok, that formulation makes no sense. However, sending inside sigmas of conducting planes to opposite signed infinities and outside sigmas to opposite signed infinity respective to their inner (ie charges would mirror each other), would do the trick, no?

Comment: Don't know why outside sigma's were necessarily zero in the first place, but that is what my prof told me when asked.

Comment: Let's forget about the charged sheet at $z$ for the moment. If the E-field is zero for $|z|< d$, what is the field inside one of the conducting sheets when it has opposite charges on opposite sides? If you are trying too see why a solution works or doesn't, please just sketch the E-field everywhere.

Comment: Ok, I will do that. To some extent yes I am because I hate this problem. However, I also do think that symmetry shouldn't be broken by grounding, and that the solution should be abuse of infinity just like infinity is abused to establish E from a plane to begin with. Furthermore, my thoughts are a little muddle because I did this problem like 5 different times 5 different ways. Finally, I have been rushing my responses because I have an analysis final tomorrow I should be thinking abt. To that end, I will take my time to sketch out the E field tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: Right! I do see why that one doesn't work either. Before, I did sketch out in my head, but screwed up. I will think about this further tomorrow.

Comment: I see that it would be impossible to create a situation where E is zero every where with "4 sheets of charge." Very annoyed that the Zhangwill solution is correct, and I was wrong, but I see why and I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

*. . . . . but I don't understand how sigma could have dependence on the position of plane.*

Let the magnitude of the electric field on the left-hand side be $E_{\rm left}$ and that on the right-hand side be $E_{\rm right}$ and the potential of the plate be $V$.

Then as the electric field is (minus) the potential gradient and uniform between the plates,
$E_{\rm left} = \dfrac{V}{d+z}$ and $E_{\rm right} = \dfrac{V}{d-z}$.
This is really a statement that the work done in moving unit charge from the left hand plate to the central plate, $E_{\rm left}\times (d+z)$, is the same as the work done in moving unit charge from the right hand plate to the central plate, $E_{\rm right}\times (d-z)$.

Unless $z=0$ this shows that the electric field produced between the plates is different and thus the surface charge density of the plates must differ.

Comment: I should rephrase that. its not that I don’t understand where z dependence in the solution comes from in the solution.   However, E due to infinite charged plane is uniform. Therefore, the response of a conductor(s) to applied E should be invariant under translations as E applied to a charge is invariant under translation (that don’t cross plane).   I am purposing a solution that maintains that property, and behaves in a way consistent with the potential theory you outline above. What is wiring w said solution?  Furthermore, the ungrounded version of this problem maintains this property.